# Prioblems with the "Deriv" R package

Tags: r, derivative

I am having two related problems with the Deriv() function from the Deriv package (from CRAN).

Problem (1):  I believe that the code in the rule for differentiating dbinom() w.r.t "prob" is incorrect.  Evidence for this (and my proposed correction) is shown in the following code.  I would have preferred to *attach* text files containing the code, but as far as I can see there is no way to do this.

```
#
# Script demo01.R.
#

library(Deriv)
# Plot dbinom as a function of probabiity.
plot(function(p){dbinom(3,8,p)},from=0,to=1,xlab="parameter \"prob\"",
     ylab="binomial probability",main="dbinom")
abline(v=3/8,col="red")
readline("Go? ")

# Plot the derivative of dbinom, with respect to prob, calculated by
# Deriv(),  as a function of probability.
Ddb <- Deriv(dbinom,"prob")
plot(function(p){Ddb(3,8,p)},from=0,to=1,xlab="parameter \"prob\"",
     ylab="",main="derivative of dbinom")
readline("Go? ")

# Replace what I believe to be incorrect code for the rule for
# differentiating dbinom() with what I believe to be correct code.
# This rule should, strictly speaking, be placed in a new environment
# rather than over-writing the existing rule, but this seems to
# break down when second derivatives are taken.
drule[["dbinom"]] <- alist(x=NULL,size=NULL,prob={
                             .e1 <- 1 - prob
                             .e2 <- size - 1
                             if (x == 0)
                                 -(x * .e1^(x - 1))
                             else if (x == size)
                                 prob^.e2 * size
                             else size*(dbinom(x-1,.e2,prob) - dbinom(x,.e2,prob)) *
                                  (if (log) dbinom(x, size, prob) else 1)
                             })

# Plot the derivative of dbinom, with respect to prob, calculated by
# the corrected version of Deriv(),  as a function of probability.
Ddb <- Deriv(dbinom,"prob")
plot(function(p){Ddb(3,8,p)},from=0,to=1,xlab="parameter \"prob\"",
     ylab="",main="derivative of dbinom, corrected")
abline(v=3/8,col="red")
abline(h=0,col="blue")
```

You will observe that the derivative of dbinom()
should be positive for prob < 3/8 and negative for prob > 3/8.  My corrected version has this property, whereas the derivative produced by the uncorrected version is negative everywhere.

Can anyone confirm that I am right about about there being a bug in the Deriv package?  (I.e. that I am not making some sort of stupid mistake?)

Problem (2). I "crosschecked" the calculations performed by Deriv() by applying this function to a "roll-your-own" version of dbinom() for which no special rule is needed.  I also applied the (corrected version) of Deriv() to dbinom().  The code that I used is as follows:

```
#
# Script demo02.
#
library(Deriv) 

# Replace what I believe to be incorrect code for the rule for
# differentiating dbinom() with what I believe to be correct code.
# This rule should, strictly speaking, be placed in a new environment
# rather than over-writing the existing rule, but this seems to
# break down when second derivatives are taken.
drule[["dbinom"]] <- alist(x=NULL,size=NULL,prob={
                             .e1 <- 1 - prob
                             .e2 <- size - 1
                             if (x == 0)
                                 -(x * .e1^(x - 1))
                             else if (x == size)
                                 prob^.e2 * size
                             else size*(dbinom(x-1,.e2,prob) - dbinom(x,.e2,prob)) *
                                  (if (log) dbinom(x, size, prob) else 1)
                             },log=NULL)

fooB1 <- function(x,prob,size) {
    dbinom(x,size,prob)
}

fooB2 <- function(x,prob,size) {
    choose(size,x)*prob^x*(1-prob)^(size-x)
}

dfooB1  <- Deriv(fooB1,"prob")
dfooB2  <- Deriv(fooB2,"prob")
d2fooB1 <- Deriv(fooB1,"prob",nderiv=2)
d2fooB2 <- Deriv(fooB2,"prob",nderiv=2)

vB1 <- fooB1(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
vB2 <- fooB2(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
dB1 <- dfooB1(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
dB2 <- dfooB2(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
d2B1 <- d2fooB1(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
d2B2 <- d2fooB2(x=3,prob=0.6,size=8)
```

If you run this code you will see that the function values (vB1 and vB2) agree, both having the value 0.123863.  Likewise the first derivative values dB1 and dB2 agree: -0.9289728.

However the second derivatives disagree.  The value of d2B1 is 1.769472, whereas the value of d2B2 is 2.064384.  I have no idea which (if either) of these answers is correct.

Something (the chain rule?) is not working as it should.

Is there any action that I can take to resolve this discrepancy?

Comment: Actually I **do** know which of d2B1 and d2B2 is correct.  Duhhh. Just calculate the derivatives by hand.  One gets the d2B2 value, i.e. 2.064384.  So it appears that Deriv() is messing up on applying the chain rule to dbinom().  Seems very strange to me.

Comment: The Bug Reports line in the output of `packageDescription("Deriv")` will show you where you can file issues with the package.

Comment: Thank you Gabor.  I was unaware of this facility.  This is obviously the appropriate way to deal with such matters.  I have now "raised an issue" on Github.